# Suggest regularly scheduled Chat Events

Tags: discussion, chat

I'd like to see more people using our [Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler). What are some chat topics we could use for Chat Events to drive some activity to chat? What would you be interested in chatting with your fellow users with?

Comment: I was going to suggest chat events in your other [chat question](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/258/dont-forget-we-have-chat), but then I couldn't think of any interesting event...

Answer (score 1):

I had a big long post being written, but went home to sleep on it and my computer rebooted so I lost it all.

In short, I'm interested in chat when there's activity there.

If you want to increase chat activity, you need to start working to make chat active. Even if its just two users talking, it still generates activity and other users are likely to stop by and visit to see whats going on.

Some suggestions for increasing activity in chat...

- Discuss mod things in chat

  - Instead of just closing a question, post it in chat first, ask for opinions and solicit close votes from users. It could even be something like one mod asking, and another mod closing at first.
  - When a mod comes to you in TL about your site (such as migrating a question), make them talk to you in our chat room instead of TL (providing the issue isn't a sensitive one that should be kept private). Sure it might be a little more inconvenient at first, but it keeps the community involved in the moderation process, and the chat active.
- Solicit opinions in chat before making a meta post asking for suggestions

  - For example, ask about chat events can be done in chat first, and them summarize the chat into a meta post to get more ideas
- Link chat in comments whenever you close a "not constructive" question.

  - Tell users that we're available in chat to discuss their question and why it is being closed, to help them refine their question, or for subjective discussions that are not appropriate for SE's Q&A format
- Say "hi" to users that come into chat

  - I know it might not seem like much, but every once in a while I'll poke my head into a chat room to see what activity is going on, and having someone say "hi" to me makes me stay around and sometimes take part in the conversation
- Don't be serious all the time - have fun in chat too!

  - Chat shouldn't always be serious. Use it to just talk about whatever comes to mind with other users. Joke around, poke fun at the world's stupidity, star really funny comments out of context, etc but most of all, just have fun in there. Users like hanging around places that are fun :)

(Ben, I know you already do many of these things already, such as bringing moderation issues up in chat. Its great, and don't stop doing it! The sites still small)

But anyways, that doesn't answer your question at all.

For events, the only things I can think of are:

- "Guest" visitors, where someone such as an HR expert, a high-rep Workplace user, or someone "famous" to SE or the Workplace will be available to answer talk in chat
- "Townhall" styled events where mods are committed to be available in chat for a specific time once a month or so to address any questions users may have
- Event to discuss site design, logo, tagline, etc